# masm32 addition subtraction division and multiplication

Tags: assembly, masm32

```
.data
msg_title db "Multiply"
A DB  4
B DB  2
C0 DB 4
C33 DB 24
C4 DB 2
C1 DB 4

buffer db 128 dup(?)
format db "(24 - A*C/4)/(2+C/A + B)= %d"
 
.code
start:

MOV AL, A
IMUL C0
IDIV C1
SUB AL, C33

MOV AL,C33 
CBW
IDIV A
MOV BL, C4
ADD BL, B
ADD AL, BL

        
MOV CL, AL      
MOV AL, BL      
CBW             

        
IDIV CL          

CBW       
CWDE      

 
invoke wsprintf, addr buffer, addr format, eax
invoke MessageBox, 0, addr buffer, addr msg_title, MB_OK
 
invoke ExitProcess, 0
 
end start
```

So the answer should be 2 but no matter which line I change it always gives 0 as the answer

I guess I'm having a problem with the addition part in the 2nd bracket

> *"MOV AL,C33
> *CBW
> *IDIV A
> *MOV BL, C4
> *ADD BL, B
> *ADD AL, BL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how your calculations relate to the formula in the format string.

The calculation in the '1st bracket' is redundant as `mov al,c33` overwrites AL. Additionally it subtracts in the wrong way.

`IDIV CL` is probably a typo for `IDIV C1`. I don't see any setup for the CL register, but if you divide 10 (in AX) by the value 4 that is in *C1*, the quotient would be 2.

**EDIT**

The amended code now performs a valid division using CL but possibly uses the operands reversed. I can't judge this because my very first remark still stands!

```
MOV CL, AL      ; AL is 10
MOV AL, BL      ; BL is 4
CBW
IDIV CL         ; 4 / 10 produces 0
```

`CBW` `IDIV BL` would divide 10 / 4 and produce 2.

---

### Full rewrite of the calculation

- Use meaningful names: A, B, and C will do in your context
- Don't store every constant in memory
- Replace division by a power of 2 with a shift to the right
- Do respect the order of the operations, especially for subtraction where the order of the operands is important

```
A db 4
B db 2
C db 4

...

mov  al, A     ; (24 - A * C / 4) -> BX
imul C
shr  ax, 2
mov  bx, 24
sub  bx, ax

mov  al, C     ; (2 + C / A + B) -> AL
cbw
idiv A
add  al, 2
add  al, B

xchg ax, bx  
idiv bl
```

In the end the result would be 20 / 5 producing 4.

Comment: Yeah just seconds before you posted the answer I happened to comment about what I think was a typo.

Comment: I just realized that I pasted the code incomplete, can you check it now?

Comment: @ArdaSenoglu The question is now quite different than the one Sep originally answered.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I think it's a bit the old problem of not spending enough time on choosing appropriate names for their variables. I can get *C4* and *C1*, but what are *C0*, and *C33* supposed to mean?

Comment: @ArdaSenoglu I have checked the new code.

Comment: I changed it but now it gave 1, also the calculation needs to be 20/10 not 10/4 "(24-4*4/4)/(2+24/4+2)="

Comment: @ArdaSenoglu Your numbers are wrong! How can there be two 24's in the formula? C=4 (from *C0*).

Comment: yes, it appears as c there as a string, but if you look at the processes, c33 is assigned to the c part MOV AL,C33 
CBW
IDIV A
MOV BL, C4
ADD BL, B
ADD AL, BL

Comment: @ArdaSenoglu Just finushed adding the correct calculation to my answer.